# Laravel API receive JSON 404 not found

Tags: php, laravel

I'm developing a Laravel 5.6 API and I'm using Resources and Collections, Route Model Binding.

To show an item, I currently use following code in my controller:

```
public function show(Todo $todo)
{
    TodoResource::withoutWrapping();
    return new TodoResource($todo);
}
```

In the Exceptions > Handler.php I have the following:

```
 public function render($request, Exception $exception)
    {
        // This will replace our 404 response with
        // a JSON response.
        if ($exception instanceof ModelNotFoundException) {
            return response()->json([
            'error' => 'Resource not found'
        ], 404);
        }

        return parent::render($request, $exception);
    }
```

This works perfectly when the item is found in the database. If the item is not in the database I get a (when using a browser):

```
"Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found"
```

When using POSTMAN rest client, I'm getting

```
{
    "message": "No query results for model [App\\Todo].",
    "exception": "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\NotFoundHttpException",
    ....
    ....
```

I would like to simply retrieve a 404 error with text "Resource not found", using both a browser or POSTMAN.

*** Update with Routing info ***

In my api.php, I have the following:

```
Route::apiResource('todos', 'TodoController');

Route::fallback(function () {
    return response()->json(['message' => 'Not Found!'], 404);
});
```

In web.php, I have:

```
Route::Resource('todos', 'TodoController');
```

What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: How are you routing your endpoints?  in both `routes/web.php` and `routes/api.php` It wil depend of which middleware are handling the request. It seems that in the `web.php`you hasn't defined the endpoint.

Comment: Edited the original post with routing information

Comment: have you aliased `ModelNotFoundException` ?

Comment: Not sure what exactly you mean with aliased. But I'm capturing the ModelNotFoundException in Exceptions>Handler.php

Comment: have you aliased that class so you can use it by that short name in the current file you are in? `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException`

Comment: That was it @lagbox. I added 'use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException as ModelNotFoundException;' on top of my Handler.php file and now seems to work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure to alias the exception class you are checking for.

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException;
```

Without this you are checking for an instance of `App\Exceptions\ModelNotFoundException`.